# Spinner: How to set default selection in spinner from database for a particular row

Tags: android

I have a spinner of countries. When I am performing the update functionality I want that whatever data is saved in database should save in edittext and spinner. For spinner I am getting an error resource not found.

I have done like this for setting the default selection data from a database to spinner,

```
// local country is added in arraylist

   ArrayList<String> arraylist_country = new ArrayList<String>();
    arraylist_country.add(memberPersonalDetailsScreenActivityController.getMemberMasterData().get(0).getL_country().toString());

       for(int i=0 ; i<length ; i++){
          if(select_member_id == member_id[i]){
             spinner_country.setSelection(arraylist_country.indexOf(local_country[i]));
          }
```

Is there any other solution to set default selection data to spinner?

Comment: If you can post some more code then it would be better to replicate the issue.Do post logcat logs also.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my issue. I have given my code over here.This way we can set defult selection to spinner from database for a particular row.

In onCreate-

```
    //Declared spinner and used ArrayAdapter

    spinner_country = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_country_susa);
    spinner_country.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    country_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.country_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    country_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_country.setAdapter(country_adapter);
```

in edit()-

```
//user defined function called in onCreate()
    String[] local_country = memberPersonalDetailsScreenActivityController.getMemberMasterData().get(0).getL_country();
    for(int i=0 ; i<length ; i++){
        if(select_member_id == member_id[i]){
             spinner_country.setSelection(country_adapter.getPosition(local_country[i]));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What i do in my code is when i open the activity and its about to load the values from the spinner, i first read from the database the table i want. In my table i have set boolean values, and only 1 value from the whole table is true. Firstly i set a default value to be true. If the user wants to change it then when you open the activity and the default value comes in, set to the spinner the new value you want to save, press save or what ever you have, and change in the db table the boolean value from the default value to the new one. Also when you open the activity set the value that is true to be the value in the spinner aswell. 
Hope this helps and i wasnt confusing:P

Here is my code, Maybe not the best written code but it works fine:

```
db.open();
        Cursor c1 = db.getAllCurrencies();
        currentCurrencyList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                currentCurrencyList.add(c1.getString(c1
                        .getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.MY_CURRENT_CURRENCY_NAMES)));
            } while (c1.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, currentCurrencyList);
        dataAdapter1
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        currencySpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);
        currencySpinner.setSelection(0);

    db.open();
    Cursor c2 = db.getCurrentCurrency();
    currentCurrencyList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    String currencySymbol = "";
    if (c2.getCount() == 1) {
        currencySymbol = c2.getString(c2
                .getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.MY_CURRENT_CURRENCY_NAMES));
    }
    currentCurrency.setText(currencySymbol);
    db.close();

    setNewCurrencyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String spinnerSelection = "";
            spinnerSelection = currencySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            db.open();
            db.updateOldCurrency();
            db.updateCurrentCurrency(spinnerSelection);
            Cursor c3 = db.getCurrentCurrency();
            currentCurrencyList3 = new ArrayList<String>();
            String currencySymbol2 = "";
            if (c3.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    currentCurrencyList3.add(c3.getString(c3
                            .getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.MY_CURRENT_CURRENCY_NAMES)));
                } while (c3.moveToNext());
                for (int i = 0; i <= currentCurrencyList3.size() - 1; i++) {
                    currencySymbol2 = currentCurrencyList3.get(i);
                }
            }
            currentCurrency.setText(currencySymbol2);
            db.close();
        }
    });
```

dpAdapter class

```
public boolean updateOldCurrency() {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(MY_CURRENT_CURRENCY_BOOLEAN, 0);
    return db.update(MY_CURRENT_CURRENCY_TABLE, args,
            MY_CURRENT_CURRENCY_BOOLEAN + "='" + 1 + "'", null) > 0;
}

public boolean updateCurrentCurrency(String rowId) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(MY_CURRENT_CURRENCY_BOOLEAN, 1);
    return db.update(MY_CURRENT_CURRENCY_TABLE, args,
            MY_CURRENT_CURRENCY_NAMES + "='" + rowId + "'", null) > 0;
}
```

Comment: is this what you were looking for m8?